# How to refresh/reload a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table View and a uibutton.

When i click on uibutton, it will display a model view control using `presentModelviewcontroller` method.

I have a text field and save button in the presentmodelview.

Please let me know how to reload table view when the user click's on presentmodelview save button

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `presentModalViewController` to be removed and then the tableView to be reloaded then use this

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

on the viewWillAppear of the initial view.

Answer (score 0):

First add the item to the array, then reload your table view.

Assuming you declared all properties needed including the array used by the data source.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *modalArray;
```

The IBAction on Save button should include the following code:

```
//Add the item to the array
[self.modalArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtField.text]];

//Rest of your code, dismiss the modal view
```

Once dismissed, you need to reload the table view to show up the recent value saved on the modal view.

```
[self.yourTableView reloadData];
```

`reloadData` will call implicitly the data source method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which will loop the array again and so show you the new value.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell,

```
YourViewControllerClass * vc = [[YourViewControllerClass alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If your view is self.view, the above code will work fine. If your view is a subview, you can remove it from its parent, reinitialize it and add it again to the parent. This answer might be a bit more precise.

Answer (score 0):

when you want reload tableview please use below line

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```